# Yii requirement status

Tags: yii

I try to upload my first small project on new VPS (Linux+php-5.3.3+ apache) and found these problem don't know why any help will be appreciated plz.

1- I have to lowercase all my folders in my project to work on Linux system with php+apache.
2- Strange problem is getting error in calling modlules function if like this....Post::xxx if change to post::xxx its ok I mean everything should be in lowercase otherwise give error like Post.PHP not found.
3- CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver?
4- I did run yii/requirements and got all below services/status FAILED and rest PASSED.

```
       - DOM extension 
       - PDO MySQL extension
       - PDO PostgreSQL extension 
       - Memcache extension    
       - APC extension 
       - Mcrypt extension 
       - SOAP extension 
       - GD extension
```

Any suggestion how make above services PASSED. as Im running MySQL db.

I look forward to hear soon.

Comment: I solved all those problems, thanks for you guys.

Comment: Care to post your own answer?

Answer (score 0):

I know that Khan have already resolved his app problem, but just to references, the answer is:

1 - The unix/linux systens are case-sensitive, so if you named a folder Post you'll need calling Post/ on your code.

2 - As in the last answer, if you are calling you class file Post so you need to change your class name as Post, because the php autoload depend of OS is case-sensitive too.

3 - It fail because the php PDO fail and Yii use it to connect to database system.

4 - Its necessary fix PDO MySQL extension the others are optional

GodFather.